# User can't like his/her own comment - DB constraint - Django

Tags: django, database, postgresql, django-models

These are my models:

```
class Post(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['user'], condition=Q(is_featured=True), name='unique featured post per user'),
        ]

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    post = models.TextField()
    is_featured = models.BooleanField(default=False)


class Comment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=500)


class Like(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['user', 'comment'], name='unique like per comment'),
        ]

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    comment = models.ForeignKey(Comment, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_positive = models.BooleanField(blank=True, null=True)
```

GOAL:

I would like to add a constraint where the `user` can't like his own comment.

I tried, but of course I can't do this:

```
models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['user'], condition=~Q('user__id__in'=Like.objects.values_list('user_id', flat=True), name='unique like per comment'),
```

Comment: Don't display the user's own comments on the page, or do a check at time of save to see if the user id matches the comment author id.

Comment: @dfundako I would like to enforce this in the DB

Comment: You can pass the author of the comment in the context in the view. You'll already know if the authenticated user is the same as the author. Just enforce it on the page.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to put a constraint like this at the database level, as stated on the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-CHECK-CONSTRAINTS):

> PostgreSQL does not support CHECK constraints that reference table
>   data other than the new or updated row being checked

So my suggestion is to validate at the model level: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects